# Passing variables and performing event between jQuery and C# with AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

Basically I have this piece of jQuery code that uses jqvmaps to render a world map and perform actions on it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="js">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
        {
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderOpacity: 0.25,
            borderWidth: 1,
            color: 'gray',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: 'orange',
            hoverOpacity: null,
            normalizeFunction: 'linear',
            scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
            selectedColor: 'red',
            selectedRegion: null,
            showTooltip: true,
            onRegionClick: function (element, code, region)
            {


                var CountryName = document.getElementById('#<%= RegionName.ClientID %>');
                var CountryCode = document.getElementById('#<%= RegionCode.ClientID %>');
                var CountryCapital = document.getElementById('#<%= RegionCapital.ClientID %>');

                var Country = document.getElementById('#<%= RegionName.ClientID %>');
                var Capital = document.getElementById('#Capital');
                //var Code = document.getElementById('#Code');

                var codeValue = code;
                var data = { CountryCode: codeValue }

                var CapitalCity = GetCapital(code);



                CountryName.value = region;
                CountryCode.value = code.toUpperCase();
                Capital.value = CapitalCity;

                Country.text= region;
                Code.text = code;


            }



        })(jQuery);

        (function GetCapital(code)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (code) {
                    alert(code.Capital)
                }
            });

        })(jQuery);

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

What I want to do is run a C# method (and passing parameters to it) when a region is clicked (inside the OnRegionClick event), get a value returned and update labels/inputs with the new info.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WorldMapDetails
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetCapital(string CountryCode)
        {
            //do your stuff
            Country Country = new Country();

            List<Country> selectedCountry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Bloxinations\Bloxinations\WorldMapInfo\WorldMapDetails\Scripts\json\Countries.json"));

            String Capital = null;

            foreach (Country c in selectedCountry)
            {
                if (c.cca2 == CountryCode)
                {
                    Capital = c.capital.ToString().ToUpper();
                }
            }

            return Capital;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the [WebMethod] with the following code but it didn't work:

```
$.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
                 data: code,
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (code) {
                     //......
                 }
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should get value code and create a json to pass,
and while passing you should `JSON.stringify` `data`

```
var codeValue = document.getElementById('#Code').value;
var data = {countryCode: codeValue}

$.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (code) {
                     //......
                 }
                 }
             });
```

Comment: I updated the code and it is still not working. Value is 'undefined'

Comment: couple of things: make   `codeValue`and `data` global variable and dont forget `var codeValue = document.getElementById('#Code').value;` By the way which `Value` is `undefined`?